# jQuery UI Draggable using GoogleAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying out jQueryUI for the first time, and I'm trying to use the draggable function, for a div as follows:
    $("#draggable").draggable();

However If I refer to the google hosted jQuery API, it doesn't seem to work : 
    script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"

But if I download and use a local copy of the library, it works : 
    script src="jquery-ui.min.js"

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the problem was not the hosted api. I was referencing the jquery.min.js file after referencing the jquery-ui.min.js. When I corrected the order, it worked. I guess jquery-ui.min.js was using assets from the jquery.min.js library, and was erroring out when it couldn't find a reference to it.